# Не переведены сообщения про липучесть хэдера

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> Navigation

> Disable stickiness

> When you check this box, the nav bar will no longer be pinned to the top of the page.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Аллилуйя! Не знал об этом крыжике. Жизнь снова прекрасна!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы строк. Будет доступно в ближайшей сборке.